# SugarCRM 6.5 - filter Account with Opportunities

Tags: sugarcrm

I'm trying to find a way to display only Accounts in the Accounts module that have some Opportunity created for them. Is there a hook to prefilter the displayed results somehow in Sugar 6.5?

Comment: what version of Sugar 6.5 do you have (because different versions have different features) and where are you trying to display this?

Comment: I actually use SuiteCRM in the latest version, which has SugarCRM 6.5 CE as a base version. I'm trying to create a filter in the Accounts module list view...